# How do I teleport players based on their teams?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a costum map which uses comandblocks to teleport players to a spot.
The commandblocks are setup under two rooms. (One for team red players and one for team blue players). I need to teleport all players frome one team to a spot (-100 100 -100).
and the other team to another spot (100 100 -100).

The problem is that the comand blocks used to teleport team blue are closer to the team red room. This means that I can't just setup the commandblock like this:

> tp  @a[r=10] 100 100 -100

How can I make shure that one team gets telepoarted to the right area.

Note: This is just an example, there are over 100 commandblocks that need to work. This probebly means that timing it right requires a lot of redstone experiance and is almost inpossibile. The best way would be if there is a command I can just use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Information taken from the wiki:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Teams

---

To teleport players in specific teams, simply add the `team=[name]` filter onto the @p command, resulting in:

```
/tp @a[r=10,team=red] 100 100 -100
```

Just note that everything is CaSe SeNsItIvE (Case sensitive). It means that 'red' is different to 'Red'. Replace the word 'red' with the name of the team.

---

To set make team, use
`/scoreboard teams add [name] [display name... (This can be more than one word)]`

And to add a player to the team, use
`/scoreboard teams join [team] [player]`

Comment: I do not have setup the teams yet, how do I add players. i'm not good with scoreboards

Comment: Look at the edit.

Comment: so when using comandblocks it will be like this: scoreboard teams join [team] [@p]

Comment: And by 'player', I mean anyone who's online in the map. You can use @p, @r and @a to do this too. Examples are: `/scoreboard teams join red @r` and `/scoreboard teams join blue somerandomguy`

Comment: Also, if it is helpful, please don't forget to mark it as an answer. (Tick under the arrows)

Comment: thank you very much. I will check when I'm at home. tomorrow I can say if it realy works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17915/discussion-between-aytimothy-and-codermaster). (Just to keep things clean for any future what-nots)

Answer (score -3):

```
/scoreboard teams join <team name> <player name> (add a player to a team)

/scoreboard teams add <team name> (create a team)

/tp @a[r=RADIUS,team=TEAMNAME] X Y Z
```

1. Create the teams
2. Add the players to their teams
3. Place a command block and paste the command
4. Edit the capitalized parts to what applies to you

and you're good to go

Comment: I'd recommend expanding this to describe the commands, and how they work in a bit more detail.  As is, this might do the trick, but doesn't do a good job of explaining *why* this solves the problem.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of aytimothy's answer, only not as well-worded, explained and formatted.